# How to build an array in an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my model:

```
function item_attributes_data($id){
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT       attributes.attribute_text,item_attributes.attr_value,item_attributes.cost
    FROM attributes
    INNER JOIN item_attributes
    ON attributes.id=item_attributes.attr_id
    where item_attributes.item_id=".$id);

    return $query->result();
}
```

And here is my controller:

```
function item_attributes()
{
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');
    $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->load->model('orderapp_model');
    $query_result=$this->orderapp_model->item_attributes_data($id);
    echo json_encode($query_result);
}
```

I retrieved the data as

```
url=localhost/ordertakeadmin/index.php/orderapp/item_attributes/
```

I got the JSON array as follows:

```
options = [{
    "attribute_text": "VEHICLE",
    "attr_value": "Truck",
    "cost": "897.00"
}, {
    "attribute_text": "MATERIAL",
    "attr_value": "Steel",
    "cost": "385.00"
}, {
    "attribute_text": "SIZE",
    "attr_value": "Medium",
    "cost": "254.00"
}]
```

But I want to build the data as

```
options = [{
    attribute_text: "SIZE",
    choices: [{
        attr_value: "Medium",
        cost: 254.00
    }, {
        attr_value: "Small",
        cost: 154.00
    }, {
        attr_value: "Large",
        cost: 280.00
    }]
}, {
    attribute_text: "MATERIAL",
    choices: [{
        attr_value: "Steel",
        cost: 385.00
    }, {
        attr_value: "Carbon Fiber",
        cost: 285.00
    }, ]
}, {
    attribute_text: "VEHICLE",
    choices: [{
        attr_value: "Truck",
        cost: 897.00
    }, {
        attr_value: "Car",
        cost: 122.00
    }]
}];
```

And Here is my database:
attribute_text         attr_value   cost
SIZE                      large         1500.00
VEHICLE              Truck           897.00
MATERIAL              Steel      385.00
SIZE                      Medium      254.00
VEHICLE              Car             855.00
VEHICLE              jeep            875.00
MATERIAL             lead            897.00

How is it possible?

Comment: please state your framework...

Comment: I used the principles of MVC architechture

Comment: That's not really a framework..

Comment: Please state the nature of the "can't be bothered" emergency.

Comment: The framework I used is codeigniter

Comment: Could you edit your question and include your database schema?  I could put it together from your queries, but it would just be easier if you could paste it.

Comment: Also, could you edit your question and include a description of the results you want (e.g. "I want all of the possible attributes for blah blah.  Each item attribute has some attributes associated with it and I want blah blah blah.").  The more detailed the better.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Also, could you edit your question to include the `attr_id` and `item_id` in your results?  I think what you're trying to do will make a lot more sense with the ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried deciphering your question, and I think you want something like this:

```
function item_attributes_data($id){
    // first get your attributes
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT id, attributes.attribute_text FROM attributes");

    $attributes = $query->result();

    $finalResult = array();

    // then get the items for each attribute
    foreach($attributes as $attribute) {
        // fetch the items
        $itemsQuery = $this->db->query("SELECT attr_value, cost FROM item_attributes WHERE attr_id=" . $attribute['id']);

        $items = $itemsQuery->result();

        $finalResult[] = array( "attribute_text" => $attribute["attribute_text"], "choices" => $items );
    }

    return $finalResult;
}
```

Comment: But still json array displays as a single array like the array that i had earlier.I need an array inside the options[].

Comment: Do you  mean an array inside `choices`?  My function does that.

Comment: i want to build an array ,(the array should named as choices)inside the options[].

Comment: I tried the above mentioned solution.But it shows the following error:"Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: Your `$itemsQuery->result()` function is probably returning an object, not an array.  I'm not really sure what database library you're using.   You'll need to fetch your `$items` results as an array, not an object.